# Pandoc fontawesome in Markdown -> Xelatex -> pdf

Tags: xetex, pandoc, markdown, fontawesome

I want to use fontawesome symbols in an md yaml-block that then get converted into latex and from there to pdf.

I used the fontawesome package in xelatex and I tried to convert a string in an md yaml-block to something like \faTwitter in latex. It didn't work, though. Pandoc either deletes the string so that it cannot render from xelatex to pdf, or it interprets it as literal, which also prevents xelatex from rendering it.

any idea how to use fontawesome with markdown and pandoc?

Comment: Could you post some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
---
header-includes:
    - '\defaultfontfeatures{Extension = .otf}'
    - '\usepackage{fontawesome}'
author: '\faTwitter @Author'
title: 'Title'
---

# My Paper
\faTwitterSquare @Author
```

Then run pandoc like this: `pandoc filename.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o filename.pdf`

[image]

Comment: I actually think that it's a bug and shouldn't be necessary at all. Glad it works for you